# SAL Annotations: _Ret_maybenull_ for std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, annotations, static-analysis

Is it possible to annotate my smart pointer-returning function with SAL?

```
_Ret_maybenull_ std::shared_ptr<MyClass> getMyObject();
```

Gives me the warning

> warning C6504: Invalid annotation: 'Null' property may only be used on values of pointer, pointer-to-member, array, or reference type: Function 'getMyObject' return. Actual type 'class std::shared_ptr'.

and not a single warning when writing this:

```
auto a = getMyObject();
a->foo();
```

Comment: https://lastsector.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/when-c-meets-sal-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

Just like this warning says `_Ret_maybenull_` cannot be applied to smart pointers of any kind, only to primitive types. As an alternative the annotation for this function could be `_Check_return_` and the annotation for `operator ->` of smart pointer (and other operators dereferencing stored pointer) `_Check_return_ _Ret_notnull_`. You may need to write your own wrappers for smart pointers to utilize this though.

Comment: Thanks. What a pity as we switched to smart pointers some time ago to improve our code base and now it hinders us from static analysis. I am hesitating to write a wrapper around a wrapper for pointers, especially since the std smart pointer classes are much better tested than something we would write ourselves.

Comment: @PhilLab This looks like a job for public implementation inheritance and `using parent::parent;` -- then you can hide `operator->` with your annotated one that simply forwards.